# mod_rewrite from GET form

Tags: forms, apache, mod-rewrite, get

I have a get form which returns a location variable into the url. My whole site's url rewriting is working apart from my get form. Whenever I submit the form, I want it to go to:

> /findus/location/locationvalue

but it currently goes to:

> find_us?location=locationvalue

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [L] # rewrite without query string parameters
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L] # one parameter
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php?$2=$3&$4=$5 [L] # two parameters
```

Comment: Mention the URL to which you are going to submit the form. Do you want the redirect to internal (not visible to the user) or external (user's browser would be redirected to the new URL)?

Comment: the find_us page submits to itself and it needs to be an external redirect

Answer (score 0):

As Phil commented, this isn't really a rewrite issue but more one of the script that is generating the form.  This will emit HTML something like:

```
<form id="some_form_name" method="post" action="some_action">
```

where "some_action" is the URI to be actioned.  If the generating script uses `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` (let's assume PHP) then it will generate the internal URI form, not the external form and this is what is happening.  To fix this, you need to modify your form code to generate actions which use the external URI format.

Comment: It does use php. It was using $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], now it's using "http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] but it's still not working:/ Any suggestions?

Comment: Phil, didn't explain myself well.  It's the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` that's _causing_ the problem.  Adding the http... doesn't help.  You need to replace this with something like `"/findus/location/$location"` assuming here that $location is the validated version of $_GET['location']